# Stochastics with induction

Tags: induction, stochastic-calculus

prove that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$:

$\sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r}(-1)^{r} = 0$.

The base step is easy, i only get lots of problems when i try to mess with the sum boundries....

so far i've tried:

$\sum_{r=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{r}(-1)^{r} = \sum_{r=0}^{n+1}(\binom{n}{r}+\binom{n}{r-1})(-1)^{r} = \sum_{r=0}^{n+1}\binom{n}{r}(-1)^{r}+\sum_{r=0}^{n+1}\binom{n}{r-1}(-1)^{r}$

Don't know how to proceed... Please help?

Comment: index on the 2nd sum cannot start with 0.

Comment: i know, thats why its weird.... i only substitute 

$\binom{n+1}{r} = \binom{n}{r} + \binom{n}{r-1}$.

Comment: that substitution works only for $r=1$,take $r=0$ out of the summation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this way:
$$
\begin{split}
\sum_{r=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{r} (-1)^r
 &= \binom{n+1}{0} + \binom{n+1}{n+1} (-1)^{n+1}
                   + \sum_{r=1}^n \binom{n+1}{r} (-1)^r \\
 &= 1 + (-1)^{n+1} 
      + \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \binom{n+1}{r+1} (-1)^{r+1} \\
 &= 1 + (-1)^{n+1} 
      - \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \binom{n+1}{r+1} (-1)^r \\
 &= 1 + (-1)^{n+1} 
      - \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{r+1} (-1)^r
      - \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{r} (-1)^r \\
 &= 1 + (-1)^{n+1} 
      + \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{r+1} (-1)^{r+1}
      - \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{r} (-1)^r \\
 &= 1 + (-1)^{n+1} 
      + \sum_{r=1}^n \binom{n}{r} (-1)^r
      - \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{r} (-1)^r \\
 & \text{cancel terms in the sum indexed $1...n-1$} \\
 &= 1 + (-1)^{n+1} + \binom{n}{n}(-1)^n- \binom{n}{0} \\
 &= (-1)^{n+1} + (-1)^n \\
 &= 0
\end{split}
$$
as desired.